# mysql query is slow, need help to optimize

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table1

time            userid  id1 id2 
9/1/2014 3:30   user1   123 555
9/1/2014 3:32   user1   123 555
9/1/2014 3:13   user1   123 555
9/1/2014 3:15   user1   123 555
9/1/2014 3:38   user2   321 555
9/1/2014 3:21   user2   321 555
9/1/2014 3:38   user2   456 666
9/1/2014 3:21   user2   456 666

table2

id1 orderid
321 order1
123 order2
```

Explain query:

```
select_type table   type possible index  key         key_len    ref        row     Extra
SIMPLE     table1   ALL                                                    934420   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
SIMPLE     table2   ref lookupindex    lookupindex    33        table1.id1  1
```

My table1 has about 1 billion rows, and table2 is lookup table that has 20k row, and order 555 is about 100 million rows. 
id2 is about 10% of total table1. table2 is basically lookup table that has all id1. id1-> orderid has many to one relation. In other word one id1 belongs to only one orderid.
table2 and table1 does not have null value except userid.

I want to calculate unique users for every orderid.

My query is taking long time to run(did not finish within 5 hours, so i stopped it), i am not sure how to optimize it other than index. I have index on table2.id1.

```
select  table2.orderid, count(distinct userid)
from table1 left join table2 on table1.id1 = table2.id1
where table1.id2="555"
group by table2.orderid
```

Does mysql do the left join first or where statement first?Should store the order 555 into different table then run they query?

Comment: fields `table1.id2`, `table2.orderid` have index?

Comment: Put "EXPLAIN" in front of your query and execute it. MySQL will spit out the execution path and optimization of your query. You can see there if it first filters for "555" before joining (which I very much suspect it does). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: [Read about `EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q: Does mysql do the left join first or where statement first? Should store the order 555 into different table then run they query?**

In theory, the optimizer is free to choose any execution plan that produces the specified result. The optimizer is supposed to be smart enough to choose an order of operations that it thinks is most efficient.

In practice, the way we write a statement, and what indexes we make available can have a significant influence on the options available to MySQL.

---

To see the execution plan the MySQL is choosing, we can use `EXPLAIN`. That shows us a summary of the operations that MySQL will perform.

[**Understanding the Query Execution Plan**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Having appropriate indexes available makes more efficient access paths available to MySQL.

Without seeing the EXPLAIN output, or a definition of the tables, and what indexes are available,  we're just guessing.

Given that the statement is very slow, we're going to venture a guess that suitable indexes aren't available, and secondly, that MySQL is spending a boatload of time on the "Using filesort" operation for the `GROUP BY` operation.)

It's also likely that the statement can be re-written to return an equivalent result, or a result that is nearly equivalent. We can throw out some recommendations to "try this" or "try that".

But let's understand the operations that MySQL needs to perform.

Firstly, there's an equality predicate on the `id2` column. If this is fairly selective (less than 10% or 20% of the total rows in `table1`, the likely an index on `table1` with `id2` as the leading column would provide an efficient access, which may give some performance benefit. (This is efficient because MySQL can use an range scan operation against the index to quickly narrow in on the requested rows, without having to look at every flipping row in the table.)

Secondly, in your query there's an "outer join" operation to find matching rows in `table2`, with an equality predicate on `id1` column. So, likely, an index on `table2` with `id1` as the leading column may be of benefit.

The query is also accessing the `orderid` column from the matched rows from `table2`; if we also include that column in the index, that would make it a "covering index", which is just a short way of saying that MySQL will have the ability to retrieve all of the values it needs directly from the index, without requiring lookups to pages in the underlying table.

If that's a lot of rows being retrieved, we could spend a lot of time sorting them (the sort operation required by the GROUP BY.)

There's a lot of information we don't have, about the cardinality of the orderid column, whether that column column can be null, the cardinality of the userid column, whether that can be null, how many rows we're expecting to be returned, and so on.

---

Before we launch into tuning this particular statement, I think we need to understand what question this query is trying to answer, and make sure that this query would in fact return the answer you're looking for. We should be open to exploring whether an equivalent answer could be returned from a different query.

It looks like you want a distinct list of `orderid` from `table2` (including possible NULL values), not all of them but only a subset, that meet certain criteria.

And along with that `orderid` value, you want a count (the number of distinct `userid` values) from the rows from table1 that have a particular value in the `id2` column.

For example, if we weren't concerned with the NULL values of `orderid`...

(That is, the NULL values that would be produced by the original query due to outer join when there are rows from table1 that don't have a matching row in table2... for every row in `table1` that doesn't have a matching row in `table2`, we know that `table2.orderid` will be NULL...)

Aside from the count for NULL orderid, the following query would return the same list of orderid and  counts...

```
SELECT b.orderid
     , COUNT(DISTINCT a.userid)
  FROM table2 b
  JOIN table1 a
    ON a.id1 = b.id1
   AND a.id2 = '555'
 WHERE b.orderid IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY b.orderid
```

For optimum performance of that query, I'd recommend covering index on table2:

```
ON table2 (orderid, id1)
```

and a covering index on table1, either/or both of:

```
ON table1 (id2, id1, userid)
ON table1 (id1, id2, userid)
```

(It's possible that we might be able to get MySQL to perform a Tight Index Scan operation to satisfy the GROUP BY, rather than an expensive sort of a temporary table ("Using filesort; Using temporary")

What we'd really like to see is the output from an `EXPLAIN` for that query, and for the original query.

(If we really do need the count for `NULL` values for `orderid`, we could write another query to get that separately.)

Comment: thank you for this great explanation. I updated my original post, it has some info about Explain query and table itself

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your distinct operation, that one is very expensive. You might make it more efficient by putting an index on userid, the two keys also should have an index. I'm not sure what you are trying to do functionally but maybe something else is possible too as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically your query:

```
select t2.orderid, count(distinct t1.userid)
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id1 = t2.id1
where t1.id2 = 555
group by t2.orderid;
```

First, you don't need the `left join`, presumably, because you are grouping by a column in the second table.  This may help a lot, if `table1` is quite large.  So, write the query without that join:

```
select t2.orderid, count(distinct t1.userid)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id1 = t2.id1
where t1.id2 = 555
group by t2.orderid;
```

Second, you want an index on `table1(id2, id1, userid)` and on `table2(id1, orderid)`.

There may be some other optimizations, depending on the nature of the data.  For instance, does `table1` contain multiple `userid` or is the `distinct` an artifact of the `join`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you count all distinct values userid and id1 (without join) and then join counted values from table1 with table2

```
SELECT orderid, a.sum 
FROM table2 
INNER JOIN     
(SELECT id1, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) as sum FROM table1 WHERE id2 = '555' GROUP BY id1) a
ON table2.id1 = a.id1
```